# Fedora: Access dynamic disk created in windows

Tags: linux, dynamic-disk

I recently decided to migrate from windows to fedora*.
Now, my problem is that my main disk was a dynamic disk. I thought I had a vague memory of this working in linux (to be specific, fedora 16), but apparently not.

**Question:**
How can I access the contents of a dynamic disk from linux/fedora?

Do note that this have to be completely non-destructive. I can't afford a new disk and my other disk isn't big enough to hold the data.

**EDIT:**
Went hunting after a driver or something similar, and happened to stumble upon two options you can tick when building the (latest) fedora kernel,

```
CONFIG_LDM_PARTITION #and
CONFIG_PARTITION_ADVANCED
```

(which both needs to be set to =y). Unfortunately, I didn't have the time to compile it (it was 1230 in the morning!), but I will do so tonight.

*Mostly since the serial key I used was registered to a school I went to before.